# An easier way of passing callback with preassigned argument in javascript?

Tags: javascript, callback, arguments, apply

I'm going to be passing a callback with a preassigned argument into another function.

I have created a fiddle but it seems over complicated. Perhaps there is an easier way of doing this:

```
a = function(b, c){
    console.log(b, c);
}

b = function(a){
    a('c');
}

b(
    (function(a, b){
        return function(c){
       a.apply(null,[b,c]);
    }
    })(a,'b')
);
```

This should output: "b c"

https://jsfiddle.net/j5gys95z/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to "fix" the first `n` arguments (see [partial application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application)):

```
b(a.bind(null, 'b'))
```

That works as long as the caller doesn't want to set the callback's `this` value, or if you want to fix other arguments than the *first* `n`. In those cases you will have define a new function and pass `this` / the arguments along as desired.